# Como fazer uma pagina de editar para cada registro?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, tenho um sistema de boletim escolar em PHP onde o responsável cadastra os alunos. O problema está na pagina de editar aluno, não consigo setar um único aluno, no link da pagina aparece o ID do aluno selecionado mas na pagina aparecem todos os que foram cadastrados pelo usuário. Já tentei colocar o ID do aluno no where do select mas também não funciona.

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço muito.

Comment: Seja Bem Vinda Mayra, pra que possamos te ajudar é necessário você colocar mais detalhes, como seu código php e mysql até o momento.

Comment: Sem o código não tem como lhe ajudar. Podem ser quatro os tipos de erro:
Erros de Sintaxe, Erros de Semântica, Erros de Lógica e Erros de Ambiente. Só analisando o seu código e o esquema das tabelas envolvidas na operação que poderemos identificar qual o erro.